# Change post-slug using wordpress API? Change permalink of a post using php / jquery?

Tags: posts, wp-admin, api

When calling  `wp_insert_post()` [see api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) there seems to be no possibility to set the post slug / the post permalink of the new entry.

e.g. is there a way to check if:

a string is possible to use as post-slug, if not available return error.

Comment: What about `'post_name' => [ <string> ] // The name (slug) for your post` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post_name` is the slug.

```
'post_name' => [ <string> ] // The name (slug) for your post
```

You'll need to query for a post with matching slug before inserting a new post, WordPress will just append a number to make it unique if there is a duplicate.

Comment: so probably with this code to check the slug first `<?php
$the_slug = 'my_slug';
$args = array(
  'name'        => $the_slug,
  'post_type'   => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $my_posts ) :
  echo 'ID on the first post found ' . $my_posts[0]->ID;
endif;
?>`

Comment: using args this way is better: `$args = array('name' => $the_slug, 'post_type' => 'any', 'post_status' => 'any', 'numberposts' => 1);`